# Do queries get triggered on any change or just when their result changes?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering whether *Cloud Firestore* queries that you listen to will fire for every change to that **collection** or just when the **result** of that specific query changes.

I am mainly interested in the behavior of the [`cloud_firestore` Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-analysis-tab-), however, I would assume that this is handled by Cloud Firestore in the back end.

Say, I have the following query:

```dart
Firestore.instance
        .collection('scores')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .orderBy('score', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots();
```

This is supposed to only return the **highest score** for a *specific user*.

I am wondering if the [`Stream` returned from `snapshots`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) will fire for any change in the collection, e.g. when a lower score is added for the user, or just when the result changes, i.e. a higher score for this user is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through empirical research I found out the following:

- The query will return an result **initially** whether there are matches or not, i.e. also when the user has no documents in that collection.
- Afterwards, it will **only** fire *when the result changes*, i.e. when the documents returned by that query are different.
  This is the case for adding the first score for that user while the query is already listening, removing the highest score while listening, and adding a higher score to the query.
  Consequently, the number of [`DocumentChange`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/documentChanges.html)'s will either be `1` or `2`.

The query will *completely ignore* any documents added or removed that do not affect the result. This is also mandatory in order to scale real-time listening.

Furthermore, the documentation *somwhat* confirms this. It is not really clear what ["contents change" at the beginning of the article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) or which documents (that are added, removed, or modified) are meant [in the `where`-query section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) are meant. However, it can be assumed that only the document and content that matters is meant, which my testing has confirmed.

Comment: If you find the documentation to be confusing or incomplete, you can use the "send feedback" button at the top of every page.